# AG-Grid format date in floating filter

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I use ag-grid in my Angular application.
How can I change the date format in an 'In range' floating filter?

E.g: The date format in my region is: 2022.01.06. The date format in angular floating filter is: 2022-01-06:
[image]